# Is it possible to fetch Linkedin company updates with PHP?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

My goal is to make a LinkedIn company updates feed on a website using the Linkedin PHP REST API or JavaScript api. This feed needs to be available to any user visiting my website, however, all the codes samples I can find are asking me to redirect visiting users to Linkedin  for OAuth so I can get an access token to make API calls. This is not what I need.

How can I make API calls for my company for any anonymous user coming to my site (without any redirection to LinkedIn)? This must be possible. I have registered an application already on Linkedin and received:

API Key: XXXXX
Secret Key: XXXXX
OAuth User Token: XXXXX
OAuth User Secret: XXXXX

A related question is what are the OAuth User Token and OAuth User secret for that were supplied to me when I registered my Linkedin application?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a token then check the part in the documentation about fetching the profile, it works exactly the same for company updates, just different url: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PHP code required to obtain company updates:

```
$token = "<your_access_token>";
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/<company_id>/updates";    
$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
  'x-li-format: json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Use the code in the link from the other answer to obtain an access token for your client.